# asp.net with Owin Swashbuckle basic configuration does not find url when using a virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I have been following a number of tutorials including [this one](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/) on adding Swagger via Swashbuckle.

From various posts, I have changed the following in my startup..

```
      //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
      // .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))      
      // .EnableSwaggerUi();

      HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
      SwaggerConfig.Register(httpConfig);      

      WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig, unityContainer);
      app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
```

And in my SwaggerConfig.cs I have...

```
    //[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

    namespace Micromine.MyApp
    {
      public class SwaggerConfig
      {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration httpConfig)
        {
          httpConfig
               .EnableSwagger(c =>
               {            
                  c.RootUrl(req => SwaggerDocsConfig.DefaultRootUrlResolver(req));         
                  c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyCompany.MyApp");             
                  c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\myapp.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
               })
               .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                   {                 
                   });
        }
```

**Problem 1.**

When I run my app, I have the following root route...

```
http://localhost/myapp/
```

Now if I try to browse to the swagger, ie enter

http://localhost/myapp/swagger

it redirects to `http://localhost/swagger/ui/index`, ie it does not have `myapp` in the path.

**Problem 2**

If I now manually browse to `http://localhost/myapp/swagger/ui/index`, I now get..

[image]

Finally, if I manually enter the following...

[image]

my routes show up.

Any ideas how I configure this?

Comment: Problem 2 I have fixed following [this FAQ](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#owin-hosted-in-iis---incorrect-virtualpathroot-handling). Now just for the first part...

Comment: Please include your comment as answer - this is very helpful and also solved problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 2** I have fixed following [this FAQ](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#owin-hosted-in-iis---incorrect-virtualpathroot-handling).

**Problem 1** is still pending, but I have just added my own button to link to the path to get to the Swagger UI, so I am not as worried about this anymore.